# Mirror a function along identity

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I need to come up with a *continuously differentiable* function $f(x)$ that satisfies

- $f(0) = 0$
- strictly increasing $\forall x > 0$
- in the region of $x > 0$:
- - first, strictly convex
- - then, strictly concave
- $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) \to 0$

Then I thought boy, this resembles pretty much $g(x) = x^3$ - if one would mirror it around $h(x) = x$ and move it a bit. However, I have no clue on how to mirror it along that axis.

Would anyone mind some hints? Or perhaps is there an easier way to get such a function $f(x)$?

Thanks

**Update**

For the moment, I will use $h(x) = \tan^{-1}(x - 10) + pi/2$ which of course has the downside that $h(0) > 0$ and $10$ is chosen rather arbitrarily.

Comment: Suggestion: Make sure $\tan$ is set to radians, choose $\Delta x=\pi/4$ and then it should work out as here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28x-pi%2F4%29%2Bsqrt%282%29%2F2

Comment: Ha! Stupid me ... That should be $\Delta x=1$ noting that $\tan^{-1}(-1)=\pi/4$ in order to define $h(x)=\tan^{-1}(x-1)+\pi/4$ which then, finally, works :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your idea is very fine!

### Inverting and shifting

Mirroring a function around $y=x$ is equivalent to finding the inverse of that function. This can be done algorithmically by interchanging $x$ and $y$ in the formula and solve for $y$:

$$
y=f(x)=x^3\text{ interchange $x$ and $y$ to get }x=y^3
$$
and solve for $y$ to obtain $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)=y=\sqrt[3] x$. So the answer to the *mirror process* should be $g(x)=\sqrt[3] x$ and the you can *shift* it by $(1,1)$ by defining
$$
h(x)=g(x-1)-g(-1)=\sqrt[3]{x-1}+1
$$
which almost solves the problem.

### Edit

But $h'(1)$ is not defined! This has to do with $f'(0)=0$ so you must alter $f$ slightly so that $f'(0)\neq 0$ before going through the steps ...

### Suggestion

The function $f(x)=\tan x$ has $f'(0)=1$ so it avoids the problem. Try to use that one!

Comment: But isn't h(0) a non-real?

Comment: Regarding $h(0)=\sqrt[3]{-1}+1=0$ there is no problem. But $h'(0)=\frac{1}{3\cdot 0^{2/3}}$ is undefined. I just added a comment regarding that in my answer.

Comment: @FooBar: If you follow the suggestion I just added, you should be able to succeed ...

Comment: Oops, it is $h'(1)$ that is not defined. My bad!

Comment: You mean tan^(-1)(x), right?

Comment: @FooBar: Yes, that one is involved!